# Distinct Records based on two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I have a table `testing` with two fields `name` and `com_date`. The values in the table are as shown below. date format is `mm/dd/yyyy`

```
Name | Com_Date

MC  |  2/1/2013
MC  |  2/2/2013
MC  |  2/5/2013
MR  |  2/4/2013
MR  |  2/5/2013
MU  |  2/1/2013
MU  |  2/2/2013
```

I Need to query for records based on distinct Name and the latest date.
latest record first and distinct record based on name.
like:

```
MC  |  2/5/2013
MR  |  2/5/2013
MU  |  2/2/2013
```

Answer (score 2):

Al you will need to use an aggregate function `Max()` with a `GROUP BY`:

```
select name, max(com_date) MaxCom_Date
from yourtable
group by name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e389e/4).

This can also be written using `row_number() over(partition by...)`:

```
select name, com_date
from
(
  select name, 
    com_date,
    row_number() over(partition by name order by com_date desc) rn
  from yourtable
) 
where rn =1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e389e/3)

The result for both is:

```
| NAME | MaxCom_Date |
---------------------
|   MC | 02/05/2013  |
|   MR | 02/05/2013  |
|   MU | 02/02/2013  |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, MAX(date)
 FROM table
 GROUP BY name
 ORDER BY 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your com_date column is in date format you can just do the following:

```
SELECT name, TO_CHAR(MAX(com_date), MM/DD/YYYY) FROM testing GROUP BY name ORDER BY name ASC;
```

If your date isn't in date format, you'll need to convert it before you stick it in MAX()